# Does a Dutch citizen need a visa to visit South Korea as a tourist?

Tags: visas, air-travel, south-korea, dutch-citizens

I am a Dutch citizen and want to visit South Korea.

Do I need a visa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC):

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> **Nationals of Netherlands for a maximum of 90 days.**
>
> Additional information:
>
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their
>   stay and documents required for their next destination.

Answer (score 7):

**You do not need a Visa.**

Korea's Visa Exeption program allows holders of ordinary (tourist) passports [from 67 countries](http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/Visa_Exemption/index.jsp) to visit for up to 90 days without a visa. The Netherlands is one of those. Note that the specifics vary by country.

[A second list](http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/Visa_free_entry_into_korea/index.jsp) covers countries like the US for which visa-free entry is allowed for up to 30/90 days.

Both lists can be accessed from Korea's [Ministry of Foreign Affairs site.](http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/application/index.jsp?menu=m_40_10) The apparently official [VisitKorea](https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRV/TV_ENG_2_1.jsp) site confirms the same.